# Graphviz. I need an attribute that changes the side of the edge exit

Tags: graphviz

I need attributes that change from the exit side of the edge:

[image]

Comment: hard to tell what you want as there is no example code specified. I think you should have a look at the compass points, see https://graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html

Comment: this has more info about ports: https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/portPos/ also section 3.1 here: https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf